# How do I move the DUAL-ly booted Win8 partition so that it keeps booting?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, windows-8, boot, partitioning

**This a laptop that came pre-installed with windows 10.** I then dual booted it with Win81, which is good since the Win10 partition is now freezing five minutes at a time.
When I boot up the original Win10, the arrangement of partitions is this, there's a picture here:
[image: My HDD configuration]
1. C-Win10 Status: (Healthy, Primary Partition)
2. D-LENOVO Status: (Healthy, Primary Partition)
3. F-Apps  Status: (Healthy, Primary Partition)
4. G-ATE! Status: (Healthy, Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Primary Partition)

***My GOAL is to move all data to F-Apps drive***
... via the method of enlarging it and moving all data to that drive and obviously, shrinking the C-Win10 drive.
I shrank the C-Win10 drive with **Partition Wizard 7.** 
But to take advantage of the free unallocated 30GB, I would need to MOVE the Win8 drive, something which spectacularly failed for me on another laptop.

Therefor my question is:
HOW do I **move** the bootable **G-ATE!**-drive in such manner that it stays bootable? Please, don't leave out any details. Thanks! <3 :)
**UPDATE:** The Win81 partition has been extended, not moved, but isn't booting any way.

*Ignoring all the partitions in front because I'm not gonna do anything to them*

Comment: always back up before you mess with the bootloader or partitions - which chances are you will need to do here.

Comment: Aint got no back up space.

Comment: Partitions can be moved. [Link](https://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/help/moving-parition.htm)

Comment: will moving boot partitions make them unbootable? @biswa

Comment: Well, @SpiderPig, I was already trying to do that, so thanks for noticing. But thank you so much for your comment, it really helped.

Comment: Combine all the small sections before F: with it. Use [easeuse partition master](http://filehippo.com/download_easeus_partition_master_home/).